# merge records in to one using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my collection structure, tried $mergeObjects , but did not know how to use in right way, please help :

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5e39b407eb2b5e4c3c80c5b0"),
"groupId":"1",
"emp" : {
    "roles" : [
        {
            "roleId" : "role1"
        }
    ],
    "designation" : [
        "Manager"
    ],
    "dept" : [
        {
            "deptId" : "dept1"
        }
    ]
}
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e39b435eb2b5e4c3c80c5b1"),
 "groupId":"1",
"emp" : {
    "roles" : [
        {
            "roleId" : "role2"
        }
    ],
    "designation" : [
        "Developer"
    ],
    "dept" : [
        {
            "deptId" : "dept2"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I want an aggregate query which merges the two documents w.r.t. "groupId" like this using mongodb

```
    {
"_id" : <some id>,
"groupId":"1",
"emp" : {
    "roles" : [
        {
            "roleId" : "role1"
        },
        {
            "roleId" : "role2"
        }
    ],
    "designation" : [
        "Manager","Developer"
    ],
    "dept" : [
        {
            "deptId" : "dept1"
        },
        {
            "deptId" : "dept2"
        }
    ]
    }
   }
```

There are around 200 to 300 fields like arrays, array of an array , array of an array of an array and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the $mergeObject operator would work in this given it overrides fields, for example the roleId in role would always be role2 in this case if $mergeObject is used. I are going to need a multistage solution combining $group to combine the record together and a $project to restructure the fields inside emp into what you want.

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$groupId",
    "roles": { "$push": "$emp.roles" },
    "designation": { "$push": "$emp.designation" },
    "dept": { "$push": "$emp.dept" },
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "groupId": "$_id",
    "roles": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$roles",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    },
    "designation": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$designation",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    },
    "dept": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$dept",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
      }
    }      
  }}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

merging arrays together without repeating values is done using operator `$concatArrays` and this is done by pushing all arrays together in `$group` then using $reduce like in previous answer by [Josh Balcitis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2383556/josh-balcitis)
another operator that gives unique result isr `$addToSet` instead of `$push` but you have to `$unwind` all array records before `$group` to add unique single records.
ex:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: {
      path: "$emp.roles",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$emp.designation",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$emp.dept",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$groupId",
      "roles": {
        $addToSet: "$emp.roles"
      },
      "designation": {
        $addToSet: "$emp.designation"
      },
      "dept": {
        $addToSet: "$emp.dept"
      },
    }
  },
]);
```

which approach is better? that depends on your data and `$group` vs `$reduce` perfomance
note: `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option is used to $prevent empty arrays from affecting whole result, its optional